# Calculating the mean of a data subset

Tags: r, mean, subset

I'm pretty new to R having only gone through the basics at uni so far so I'm sorry if this is a really simple question that's been answered before.

Basically this is how my data looks right now. I've subsetted the Plants, Treatments and Soils. What I need to do is figure out how to calculate the mean of the `ShootFresh` and `RootFresh` of each plant for the control and competition treatments for each of the soil types. My efforts so far just calculate the mean of each plant `ShootFresh` and `RootFresh` in the control and competition but combine the soils.... I can't seem to figure out how to use all three factors.

[image: Image of data]

This is the code I'm using at the moment

```
tapply(F.ovina$ShootFresh,F.ovina$Treatment,FUN=mean)
```

Again I'm really sorry if this has been asked but I couldn't make heads or tails of any other answers!

Comment: Try `with(F.ovina, tapply(ShootFresh, list(Treatment, Plant, Soil), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE))` or any of the `aggregate/dplyr/data.table` options by specifying 3 variables as the grouping variable.  If you are using `dplyr`, `F.ovina %>% group_by(Treatment, Plant, Soil) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))` gets both the `ShootFresh` and `RootFresh` mean for those group combinations.

Comment: Thanks you akrun that seemed to work perfectly! @akrun I have a lot to learn when it comes to R

Comment: A screenshot of data isn't very helpful. [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) for advice on how to ask your next question.

Comment: @AmyReddick feel free to answer your own question with an example using your data